# Pushing objects into dynamic keys

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an empty **array**, a **value** and an **object**. Since I have many objects, I would like to categorize them. Somehow like this:

```
ARRAY 
  KEY
    OBJECT
    OBJECT
  KEY
    OBJECT
```

This is the array, which is empty by default:

```js
public serviceTable: Services[] = [];
```

This is its interface:

```js
export interface Services {
  details:
    {
      service: string,
      description: string
    }
}
```

This is the object that I get from `result`:

```js
data: {
  details: [
    {
      service: this.formMain.get('service')?.value,
      description: this.formMain.get('description')?.value
    }
  ]
}
```

And last but not least, this is how I try to define the dynamic key of that array and its object.

```js
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
  if (result) {
   if (!Object.keys(this.serviceTable)[result.section]) {
     // No section found, lets create it ...
     this.serviceTable[this.randomNumber] = [result];
     console.log(this.serviceTable, 'ServiceTable')
   }
   else {
     this.serviceTable[this.randomNumber].push()
   }
}
```

The if-statement works good but there is something wrong with else-statement since I get this error:

> TS2339: Property 'push' does not exist on type 'Services'.

I probably get this error because `this.serviceTable[this.randomNumber]` is not an array.

So if the key (`this.randomNumber`) does not exist in the array, it will be created. But if it already exists, I want to add the new object into the same key.

So my goal is to loop the array and call all objects that belong to a specific key, somehow like this:

```js
for (let item of this.serviceTable[3]) { // Instead of a number, it could also be a string. For instance, this.serviceTable['myCategory']
  console.log(item.service); // This should list all 'services' that belong to the key '3'
}
```

How can I do this?

---

See an example of my code on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gwtceu?file=src/app/dialog-overview-example.ts).

Comment: Try initializing your array as an associative array, like so `public serviceTable: {[key: number]: Services[]} = {};`

Comment: I updated the comment so that your serviceTable will hold arrays of services.

Comment: I'm actually wondering how `this.serviceTable[this.randomNumber] = [result];` is supposed to work. `this.serviceTable[someindex]` is of type `Service` and can't be assigned an array. And for the same reason you can't do `this.serviceTable[someindex].push()`, because, again `this.serviceTable[someindex]` is not an array but a `Service`

Comment: @derpirscher, the value has to be an array of `Services`.

Comment: @Chin.Udara How? The declaration is `serviceTable: Services[]` . So `serviceTable` is an array of `Services`, thus `serviceTable[i]` is an instance of `Services` but not an array ...

Comment: @derpirscher, yes it is THE bug. Check the comment above.

Comment: Might be. But according to OP, the whole code works, except the `push`. And that's what I was wondering about ...

Comment: Yes so the error explains no? `Property 'push' does not exist on type 'Services'.` because it is not an array.

Comment: @Chin.Udara You don't get my point:  `this.serviceTable[this.randomNumber] = [result];` shouldn't work either. But OP says it does ...

Comment: Oh yeah. It does not even show a warning in StackBlits.

Comment: Ok. Now I see it. The definition of the `Services` type in the linked Stackblitz differs from the one you have given here. So actually, i. The Stackblitz your Services type is array like (ie its keys are numbers), so you can assign an array to it. But it's not an Javascript array, so it doesn't have the push method ...

Comment: Please get your code here straight. It seems to differ from the code you are actually using. And fruthermore it seems to access properties (like `section`) that are not mentioned anywhere. Questions should be self contained and consistent on their own. Links to external resources might help, but shouldn't be inconsistent with the content of the question.

Comment: @derpirscher I have updated my question. So you may find the full code on BitBucket. Hope that helps.

Comment: Please get the code HERE consistent. Most of the folks browsing through questions are not really interested in scraping through apps on stackblitz or full respositories.

Comment: @derpirscher most relevant code I have already posted HERE. As I have described in my question, I have an array, a value and an object. All of them are posted in my question. Also, the question itself is clear. If there is something not clear to you, you can ask.

Comment: Yes, but as stated in my comments multiple times, the code posted here differs from the code at stackblitz and is also inconsistent with the described behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is your interface. Keep it as it is, but add the following additional line:

```js
export interface Sections extends Array<Services> {}
```

Then you may need to replace

```js
public serviceTable: Services[] = [];
```

with

```js
public serviceTable: Sections[] = [];
```

Since you now have an array, you may use `this.serviceTable[this.randomNumber].push(result)` without getting any errors.

Related to your goal, this is how you could loop the array to retrieve objects from affected key:

```js
// Almost the same as your own code, but you forgot 'details'
for (let item of this.serviceTable[3]) {
 console.log(item.details.service);
}
```

Comment: That would still leave an incompatibility in structure between the `Services` and the `result`, because in the `Services` interface `details` is an *object*, whereas in the result `details` is an *array of objects*

Answer (score 1):

The code you have in your linked Stackblitz differs from the code you show here. Especially the definition of the `Services` interface. And that's also the reason for your issues (and why I couldn't understand how your code could possibly compile)

In your question, the `Services` interface looks like this

```
export interface Services {
  details:
    {
      service: string,
      description: string
    }
}
```

Whereas in the Stackblitz it looks like this

```
export interface Services {
  [details:number]:
    {
      service: string,
      description: string
    }
}
```

Which is a totally different type. A valid instance of the first interface looks like this

```
{ 
  details: {
    service: "foo",
    description: "bar"
  }
}
```

Whereas a valid instance of the second interface looks like this

```
{ 
  1: {
    service: "foo",
    description: "bar"
  }
}
```

Ie the keys in your second interface are numbers, thus is array-like. And that's also the reason why you were able to do this assignment

```
this.serviceTable[this.randomNumber] = [result];
```

But of course, it's still not an array, thus it does not have a `push` function (well, it actually will have at runtime, because you are assigning a real array, but the compiler can't be sure if that, so it raises an error)

And you have a third type, which is related to that issue. That's the type of your `result` object, which looks like the following

```
data: {
  details: [
    {
      service: this.formMain.get('service')?.value,
      description: this.formMain.get('description')?.value
    }
  ]
}
```

Which is again totally different type. And if you do

```
this.serviceTable[this.randomNumber] = [result];
```

you will be assigning a structually incompatible array, because result contains a `data` property, which doesn't exist in any of the other mentioned types. And also the `details` property here is an array, whereas it is an object in the two other interfaces. This currently works in your stackblitz because `result` is of type `any` (and the blitz actually shows an error about that). If `result` was properly typed, the above assignment would also raise an error.

The easiest way to deal with that issue is probably to define the servicetable as an array of arrays.

```
servicetable: Services[][] = [];
```

And use the first definition of the `Services` interface (ie the one from the question and not from Stackblitz).

And you would need to change the way, you create the `result` into the following

```
let result = {
  details: {
    service: this.formMain.get('service')?.value,
    description: this.formMain.get('description')?.value
  }
}
```

or this

```
let result = {
  data: {
    details: {
      service: this.formMain.get('service')?.value,
      description: this.formMain.get('description')?.value
    }
  }
}
```

But then when you add this result to your servicetable you need to refer to that data as `result.data` ...

Furthermore I'm actually wondering, what the sense of this `push()` without a value would be? Or did you mean to do `push(result)`?

If that's the case, that should also work with the changed definition of the `servicetable` and `result` object.